# Play migration issue using scala2.9.2

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.1

I am migrating play 2.0 to 2.1 and, made following changes in my code

```
@(syns: scala.collection.immutable.List[SynonymMapping], filter: String,msg:scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String])(implicit session:play.api.mvc.Session,request: play.api.mvc.RequestHeader)

@cmsmain("View Mapping",Some("mapping"),nav="viewmapping")
```

I am getting following error after this.

```
both method requestHeader in object PlayMagicForJava of type => play.api.mvc.RequestHeader
    [error]  and value request of type play.api.mvc.RequestHeader
    [error]  match expected type play.api.mvc.RequestHeader
    [error] @cmsmain(title="View Mapping",Some("mapping"),nav="viewmapping") {
```

Not able to understand whats going worng here any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

There are two instances/sources of RequestHeader marked as implicit where you call your template from so the Scala compiler does not know which one to choose for the implicit argument to the template. One of the implicits comes from PlayMagicForJava the other one is a value called request, so probably the request you accept to your controller action.